# Correlation between selfie and Narcissism

Tags: love, self

Are there scientific evidence to correlate selfie pictures and Narcissism? I am curious when and after what threshold does self love move into the Narcissistic phase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Self-reported number of selfies has been  found to correlate positively with some measures of narcissism in US men (Fox and Rooney, 2015).

> Fox, J., & Rooney, M. C. (2015). The Dark Triad and trait self-objectification as predictors of men’s use and self-presentation behaviors on social networking sites. Personality & Individual Differences, 76, 161-165. doi: 10.1016/j.paid.2014.12.017

Comment: Can you sum up the research method?