# How strong is the correlation between selfies and narcissism?

Tags: personality, correlation

We have concluded that posting selfies is correlated with narcissism, but **how strong is the correlation?**

Reference: [Correlation between selfie and Narcissism](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9542/correlation-between-selfie-and-narcissism)

Comment: Have you checked [the paper referenced in that post](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/9543/21):? I would be surprised if they do not list it? Possibly ask for elaboration on that answer, instead of posting this as a separate question?

Comment: I can't find any source where I can read the article. I could only find abstracts with not clear answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Table 1  of Fox and Rooney (2015) report this correlation between selfies posted on social networks and narcissim to be r = .19 in a sample of 800 U.S. men, (mean age = 29, SD = 6.5). I.e., the observed correlation was small in a general sense. But in the broader domain of personality-behaviour correlations, .19 is fairly moderate.

> Participants’ selfie posting behavior was assessed with one item
>   inquiring how many pictures they had taken of themselves and posted on
>   SNSs in the past week (M = 0.56, SD = 2.33; min = 0, max = 30).

[image: table of correlations photos taken, selfies and narcissism]

Fox, J., & Rooney, M. C. (2015). The Dark Triad and trait self-objectification as predictors of men’s use and self-presentation behaviors on social networking sites. Personality & Individual Differences, 76, 161-165. doi: 10.1016/j.paid.2014.12.017